# AngularJS app on NginX: http response 304 on mobile

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have an AngularJS hosted on a Amazon Web Server running Ubuntu. I displays without errors on desktop computers across all modern browsers.

But it is not shown on mobile devices. I tried on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (Android 4.2), Ipad and Iphone 6+. None of them is working.

In the NginX access.log I can see that all requests from the mobile devices gets 304 responses, where desktop browsers all get 200 as they should.

I do not have a clue as to where I should start to find the error. What could be possible sources to this error? Any experiences shared is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: hmm 304 is normal to me, just not modified.

Comment: If you need to have a 200 code, you may try to clear cache of your phone browser.

Comment: You may have disabled cache in general or [disabled cache while devtools is open](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings#disable-cache) in Chrome for example. This way you'll always get a 200 on desktop.